# PHP Codeigniter Amazon / Ebay type of Search Results

Tags: php, codeigniter, search

I have a project that is using Codeigniter. I'm looking for a search that will help drill down into specific results, similiar to Amazon and Ebay (sidebar with options based off of results).

Before I attempt to tackle this from scratch, I wanted to know if there's an easier way (or plugin) to get started on this.

I've done searching and saw that Amazon has a name for their search (A9) but no information on usage or purchasing.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an indexing server. `Solr` or `ElasticSearch`. You index you data from `MySQL` (or other DB) to one of those 2 servers. Then you connect your search Model to that server and query data. Each of those servers can provide [faceted search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faceted_search) where you can build ebay/amazon like filter form.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I honestly didn't know what words to search for, this points me in the right direction for this project.